Azure Logic app standard - set vnetPrivatePortsCount via Terraform
We have a requirement to set the vnetPrivatePortsCount which is a Configuration setting of Standard logic app. However, so far we could not find a way to set it via terraform. We use azurerm_logic_app_standard object to create Logic apps so we need an option to set it via that.
We have tried doing below but that does not work
site_config {
vnet_private_ports_count = 2
}

Is this property not available via terraform or am I missing something?
Our terraform version is 1.8.5
and azurerm version is 3.106.1

Based on the documentation and the current capabilities of the Terraform provider for Azure, the vnet_private_ports_count property is not supported for the azurerm_logic_app_standard resource directly @vijaysharma

you can use cli commands if you want to achieve this by using these commands with null resource


Azure Logic app standard - set vnetPrivatePortsCount via Terraform

As per the documentation by hashicorp the vnet_private_ports_count for logic App standard doesn't support as this feature need to be added.
Meanwhile we can leverage the same requirement using the CLI commands using null resource.
Terraform configuration:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = var.app_service_plan_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku {
    tier = "WorkflowStandard"
    size = "WS1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "example" {
  name                = var.logic_app_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  site_config {
    always_on = true
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "set_vnet_private_ports_count" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
    command = <<EOT
      az resource update --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.example.name} --name ${azurerm_logic_app_standard.example.name} --resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/sites' --set properties.siteConfig.vnetPrivatePortsCount=2
    EOT
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_logic_app_standard.example]
}

variable.tf:
variable "resource_group_name" {
  default = "vinay-resources"
}

variable "location" {
  default = "East US"
}

variable "app_service_plan_name" {
  default = "vinay-appserviceplan"
}

variable "logic_app_name" {
  default = "vinay-logicapp"
}

variable "storage_account_name" {
  default = "sampvksbeacct"
}

Deployment succeeded:


Reference:
We can check with supported versions from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.logic/allversions

We tried this approach but it threw error : "Please run az login' to set up account". How can we login via terraform?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli
you can refer to this for authentication using the service principle @VijaySharma

resource "null_resource" "set_vnet_private_ports_count" {
provisioner "local-exec" {
interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
command = <<EOT
az login --service-principal -u ${var.client_id} -p ${var.client_secret} --tenant ${var.tenant_id}
az resource update --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.example.name} --name ${azurerm_logic_app_standard.example.name} --resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/sites' --set properties.siteConfig.vnetPrivatePortsCount=2
EOT
}
this will make you overcome the authentication issue @VijaySharma

Thankyou so much @Vinay B , It has worked for us!!

You can instead run these commands through a provisioner with terraform!
get access token for the active subscription

az account get-access-token

get access token for a specific subscription

az account get-access-token --subscription ""


You can do this via the azapi provider and the azapi_update_resource resource as follows (update your resource names as required):
resource "azapi_update_resource" "example" {
  type        = "Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01"
  resource_id = azurerm_logic_app_standard.example.id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      siteConfig = {
        vnetPrivatePortsCount = 2
      }
    }
  })
  
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_logic_app_standard.example
  ]
}

I'm not certain if the explicit dependency is required FYI, it might be fine without it, but they include it in the example.
